# Google App Scripts remove duplicates without deformatting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following script for removing duplicates in my Google Sheets, but when it removes the duplicates, the data validation (Tick boxes) in empty cells also will be removed. I use the following app script:

```
function deleteduplicates() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Orders').getRange('A:Q').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().removeDuplicates().activate();
};
```

Is there a solution that duplicates will be removed (just the complete row of the duplicate), and that the data validation will not be deleted in the empty cells?

Thanks in advance

:)

Comment: Could you show a "before" and " after " screenshot of a sample?

Comment: Consider providing a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, clearly indicating the expected and the actual outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have thought of a workaround but it will requires you to create conditional formatting rules.

I create a conditional formatting rule to highlight duplicates then use apps script to remove duplicates and add a new row with data validation rules.

**Conditional Formatting:**

Apply to range: A:D

Custom Formula: `=countifs($A$1:$A1,$A1,$B$1:$B1,$B1,$C$1:$C1,$C1,$D$1:$D1,$D1)>1`

**Script:**

```
function deleteduplicates() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  //Only get range with data (non-empty cells)
  var firstCol = sheet.getDataRange();

  //Save data validation rules based on the first row
  var dataValRules = sheet.getRange('A1:D1').getDataValidations();

  var maxRow = firstCol.getNumRows();
  for (var row=1; row<=maxRow; row++){

    //Delete row with background color of gray #999999
    if(sheet.getRange(row,1).getBackground() == "#999999"){

      sheet.deleteRow(row);

      //since current row was deleted adjust current data set
      //this will handle scenarios with succeeding duplicates
      row--;
      maxRow--;

      //insert new row at the end and set data validation rules
      sheet.insertRowAfter(maxRow);
      sheet.getRange(maxRow,1,1,4).setDataValidations(dataValRules);
    }
  }
};
```

**Before:**

[Sheet Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqOqL.png)

**After:**

[Sheet After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FafTn.png)